# Install mod_websocket module in ejabberd 2.1.11 Windows

Tags: windows, websocket, installation, ejabberd

I want to install websocket module (mod_websocket) in ejabberd 2.1.11 Windows,
From the site https://github.com/superfeedr/ejabberd-websockets , I cant find the detail instruction how to install it on Windows.

What should I do about that?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

superfeedr doesn't support mod_websocket any more. Currently mod_websockets isn't standard, you can't use WebSocket from webclient to connect to ejabberd.